# D-ary max heap implementation

Tags: c++, beginner, performance, algorithm, heap

I implemented a D-ary max heap backed by a vector for resizing. I would like to know any possible improvements in performance, design, and in the code in general.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Comparators.h"

template<typename T>
class DHeap
{

public:
    DHeap();
    DHeap(unsigned);
    ~DHeap();

    T extractMax();
    void insert(const T&);
    T increaseKey(unsigned, const  T&);
    bool empty() const{ return vec.size() == 0; }

private:
    std::vector<T> vec;
    int D;

    void maxheapify(unsigned);
    void swim(int);
    unsigned max(unsigned, unsigned) const;
    unsigned firstChild(unsigned) const;
    int parent(int) const;
    void ensureCapacity();
    int cmp(const T &, const T&) const;
    int cmpI(unsigned, unsigned) const;

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const DHeap<T>& p)
    {
        for (const T& d : p.vec)
            os << d << " ";
        return os;
    }
};




template <typename T>
DHeap<T>::DHeap() : DHeap(4){}

template <typename T>
DHeap<T>::DHeap(unsigned d) :D(d){}


template <typename T>
DHeap<T>::~DHeap(){}

template <typename T>
T DHeap<T>::extractMax()
{
    if (vec.size() < 1)
        throw new std::underflow_error("underflow");

    T max = vec[0];
    vec[0] = vec.back();
    vec.pop_back();
    maxheapify(0);

    return max;
}

template <typename T>
void DHeap<T>::insert(const T &element)
{
    ensureCapacity();
    vec.push_back(element);
    swim(vec.size()-1);
}

template <typename T>
T DHeap<T>::increaseKey(unsigned index, const T &element)
{
    if (cmp(element, vec[index]) < 0)
        throw new std::invalid_argument("new key must be greater than previous");

    T old = vec[index];
    vec[index] = element;
    swim(index);

    return old;
}

template <typename T>
void DHeap<T>::maxheapify(unsigned index)
{
    unsigned first = 0;
    while ((first = firstChild(index)) < vec.size())
    {
        unsigned largest = first++;
        while (first <= D*(index + 1) && first < vec.size())
            largest = max(largest, first++);

        if (cmpI(largest,index) <= 0) break;

        std::swap(vec[largest], vec[index]);
        index = largest;
    }
}

template<typename T>
unsigned DHeap<T>::max(unsigned a, unsigned b) const
{
    return cmpI(a, b) < 0 ? b : a;
}
template<typename T>
int  DHeap<T>::cmp(const T & a, const T& b) const
{
    return Comparators::compare(a, b);
}
template<typename T>
int DHeap<T>::cmpI(unsigned i, unsigned j) const
{
    return cmp(vec[i], vec[j]);
}

template <typename T>
void DHeap<T>::swim(int index)
{
    int p = 0;
    while (index > 0 && cmpI(p = parent(index), index) < 0)
    {
        std::swap(vec[p], vec[index]);
        index = p;
    }

}

template <typename T>
unsigned DHeap<T>::firstChild(unsigned index) const
{
    return D* index + 1;
}
template <typename T>
int DHeap<T>::parent(int index) const
{
    return (index - 1) / D;

}
template <typename T>
void DHeap<T>::ensureCapacity()
{
    if (vec.size() == vec.capacity())
        vec.reserve(3 * vec.size() / 2 + 1);
}
```

This are some template method that I use for comparing inside the heap

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

namespace Comparators
{

    template<typename T>  int compare(const T &, const T &);
    template<typename T>  int compare(const T*, const T*);
    template<typename T>  int compare(T*, T*);
    template<typename T>  int compare(std::shared_ptr<T> a, std::shared_ptr<T> b);


    template<typename T>
    int compare(const T &a, const T &b)
    {
        std::less<T> func;

        if (func(a, b)) return -1;
        if (func(b, a)) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    template<typename T>
    int compare(const T* a, const T* b)
    {
        return compare(*a, *b);
    }

    template<typename T>
    int compare(T* a, T* b)
    {
        return compare(*a, *b);
    }

    template<typename T>
    int compare(std::shared_ptr<T> a, std::shared_ptr<T> b)
    {
        return compare(*a, *b);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the signature:

```
template<typename T>
class DHeap;
```

This is unsufficient. You provide some default comparators, which would be fine if my type happened to have `operator<` implemented. But what if it didn't? You need to let the user provide his own comparator. Also you are using 3-way compare when simple binary is sufficient. The typical way to do this would be:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
class DHeap;
```

And have a member variable `Compare compare`, and add constructors to let the user pass in a `const Compare&`. You should then drop your `Comparators.h`

**Interface**

`bool empty() const` should return `vec.empty()`, not `vec.size() == 0`.

For performance, typically instead of providing `T extractMax()`, you should provide:

```
T const& maxElement() const; // or top()
void pop();
```

There are two reasons for this. The goal of a heap is to make it as efficient as possible to grab the top element. As you wrote it, `extractMax()` is logarithmic (because `maxheapify()` is). So that sort of defeats the purpose. Secondly, because you're extracting at the same time, you're requiring an additional copy (you can't return a reference because it would dangle). So that's less efficient too. This way, you can have a constant time zero-copy implementation:

```
T const& top() const { return vec[0]; }
```

Though one comment on `extractMax`, you would have definitely wanted to *move* into `max`, not copy:

```
T max = std::move(vec[0]);
vec[0] = std::move(vec.back());
```

For those types that have cheap move, this will save you some time.

You also don't need a destructor. The default one works great.

Should `increaseKey()` really be a public (or any) member? The user shouldn't be aware of the actual indices in your data structure. That seems like it breaks encapsulation to me.

**Insertion**

For C++03, `void insert(const T&)` is correct and sufficient. For C++11, we can do a lot better. First, I want to be able to *move* a `T` into your heap, so you should support that:

```
void insert(T&& element) {
    ensureCapacity();
    vec.push_back(std::move(element));
    swim(vec.size() - 1);
}
```

And also I should be able to construct an element in place. Because why should I incur an extra copy/move if I don't have to?

```
template <typename... Args>
void emplace(Args&&... args) {
    ensureCapacity();
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    swim(vec.size() - 1);
}
```

That should do it.

**Implementation Details**

`maxheapify` is confusingly implemented. I have trouble following the loop since you're trying to do too many things on one line. First, the inner loop:

```
unsigned largest = first++;
while (first <= D*(index + 1) && first < vec.size())
    largest = max(largest, first++);
```

That is the same as:

```
unsigned largest = first++;
while (first <= D*(index + 1) && first < vec.size()) {
    largest = max(largest, first);
    ++first;
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
for (unsigned largest = first, ++first;
     first <= D * (index + 1) && first < vec.size();
     ++first) 
{
    largest = max(largest, first);
}
```

Oh I get it now, we're finding the max of all the children. Also `max` is a very confusing function here. `max` to most people means `std::max()`, so my initial thought as that obviously `first > largest` at every iteration. And then I found your implementation. Let's not do it this way, and use the compare directly:

```
largest = compare(vec[largest], vec[first]) ? first : largest;
```

That is easy to understand. And let's actually factor out that loop that I wrote up there. So full rewrite of that function:

```
template <typename T>
void DHeap<T>::maxheapify(unsigned index)
{
    while ((unsigned first = firstChild(index)) < vec.size())
    {
        unsigned largest = findLargest(first, 
                             std::min(firstChild(index + 1) + 1, vec.size()));
        if (compare(vec[largest], vec[index])) {
            break;
        }

        using std::swap;
        swap(vec[largest], vec[index]);
        index = largest;
    }
}

template <typename T>
unsigned DHeap<T>::findLargest(unsigned from, unsigned to)
{
    unsigned largest = from++;
    for (; from < to; ++from ) {
        largest = compare(vec[largest], vec[from]) ? from : largest;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

I find that much easier to parse. Note also the `using std::swap`. That let's ADL find `swap()` if necessary.